# regex to capture kernel versions in a range

Tags: java, regex, linux, linux-kernel

I need a regex to capture the linux kernel versions between 2.6.32-491.el6 (inclusive) and 2.6.32-504.14.1.el6 (exclusive). Any ideas ?

^([2]{1}.[6]{1}.[3][2]-([4][9][1-9].*|[5][0][0-3].*|[5][0][4]."missing_this_part").el6)

Comment: A regexgeek would post his attempts

Comment: Are you sure a string comparison wont' be simpler?

Comment: You'll get a lot more willing help when you show the effort you've put in first!

Comment: ^([2]{1}\.[6]{1}\.[3][2]\-([4][9][1-9].*|[5][0][0-3].*|[5][0][4].<<<<missing this part>>>>)\.el6)$

Comment: @vks Maybe he's forgotten to append a number, e.g. `regexgeek2020` ?

Comment: @Jan hehhe m surprised how this nick was never used before and was avialable :)

Comment: Wow.  That's quite a bit more verbose than necessary `[2]{1}\.[6]{1}\.[3][2]\-` = `2\.6\.32-`.

Comment: You said you need this regex. What happens if you don't get it?

Comment: The task is quite non-trivial, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the obvious. It's quite non-trivial task regarding to the example you posted. There are many kernel builds in many distributions and they might differently interpret the string representation of the package version. Thus, you have to use your package manager if you have only distribution kernels.

For `rpm` you may consult with answer on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76597/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-highest-version-kernel-rpm-installed. It's also possible to get it for non-installed packages.

For Debian `dpkg --compare-versions` does the thing. For the rest you have to do a research yourself.

Returning to Java bindings. Unfortunately even lovely `librpm` has no native Java binging, though I have no idea about the rest of package managers.

Answer (score 0):

your regex is too complex, this would do:

```
2\.\6\.32-(49[1-9]|50[0-4])([\.0-9]+)\.el6
```

Here i'm assuming that your regex library uses `()` as grouping operators; in some libraries you have to escape the parentheses in order for it to be interpretted as grouping operators.  Modify as needed.

Comment: thank you! how do i check for 2.6.32-504.14.1 and lower vs 2.6.32-504 ? Regex lets me ask for specific digits and one or more of them, but I need none as an option too.

Comment: And this doesn't help. See my answer why.